# Used 'needs-validattion' bootstrap in the HTML javascript ,but it's not going inside the check validation method

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a two text fields and one submit button in my application. When I click the submit button if any one of the text field is empty it should tell me 'Please fill out the field'. So I used bootstrap 'needs-validation' in my script. Now when I click the submit it is not going inside the if or else loop of the validation. If the condition is true it should go inside the else loop and should do the ajax call.If the ajax call is success it should send the alert message to the user. But I dont see the alert message and POST call is also not happening.

My HTML script is

```js
        (function () {
            'use strict';
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                console.log("I am inside function");
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                        console.log("I am inside submit")
                        if (form.checkValidity() === False) {
                            console.log("I am inside true");
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("I am inside else");
                            var departments = $("#role").val();
                            var facultyList = $("#faculty").val().split(',');
                            facultyList.pop();
                            console.log(facultyList);

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '/departments/add',
                                data: {
                                    'role': departments,
                                    'facultylist': JSON.stringify(facultyList)
                                },
                                success: function (result) {
                                    alert("The department has been added");
                                    document.location.href = "/department";
                                }
                            })
                        }                   
                       
                        form.classList.add('was-validated');
                }, false);
            });
        }, false);
        }) ();
```

```html
<div class="row top-space-30">
            <form class="needs-validation">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="deprole">Department :</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="role" name="deprole" type="text" placeholder="QA" class="form-control input-md"
                            required>
                        <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="faculty">Faculties:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="faculty" required>
                        <input type="hidden" id="TestHidden" value="{{result}}" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4 top-space-30">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

When I run the script I can see in the console log 'I am inside submit'. But When I click the submit button without entering the details I dont see 'I am inside true' in the console log. But validation will happen. When I enter the details in two fields and click the submit button I dont see 'I am inside else' in the console log and I dont see the alert function in my application also

What I need is:
-When I click the submit button with details I should see the ajax call and should see the alert message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems..

- The JS boolean value should be `false` not `False`
- The `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` should be called regardless of validation
  since you want to stop the default behavior of the submit button

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/wtSkr8Eucc

```
  var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {

                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                    console.log("I am inside true");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("I am inside else");
                    var departments = $("#role").val();
                    var facultyList = $("#faculty").val().split(',');
                    facultyList.pop();
                    console.log(facultyList);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '..',
                        body: {
                            'role': departments,
                            'facultylist': JSON.stringify(facultyList)
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert("The department has been added");
                        }
                    })
                }                   

                form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the 'Submit' button, your form makes a default action, which is sending the form data (in a form of GET attribute) to the same page that holds the form (normally those can be controlled by the 'action' and 'method' attributes of form tag).

That in effect means that the page 'reloads' itself before executing any JS code.

To prevent that default action, add event.preventDefault(); in your event listener code block and it should be fine.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("I am inside submit")
```

Also important, don't rely on browser validation, which can be easily avoided. Make sure to implement a back-end validation / sanitation function as well.